# SQL LEFT JOIN with WHERE class

Tags: sql

there are two tables TABLE1 and TABLE2 in TABLE1 there are records which does not exist in TABLE2 with left join below i wanted to query all records which are in TABLE1 if the record does not exist in table2 however.

Note: about WHERE class in my code that is required this is because, there can be several records in the name of 'IN PROGRESS' in TABLE2 with one record in the name of 'GRADUATED' i wanted to distinct records based on table 1 ID that if there is any record in the name of 'GRADUATE' it should show only that else it should show inprogress.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       TABLE1.ID, 
       TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2
    ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.FK_ID_CLASS
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT 
           TABLE1.ID, 
           TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK
    FROM TABLE1
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2
        ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.FK_ID_CLASS
    WHERE TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED')
OR TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED'
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result (as well formatted text.)

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: What database are you use?

Comment: the question is about outer join,  Mureinik,

Comment: i am using oracle command prompt Michael Piankov

Comment: Michael Piankov may i please ask you to share your skype id, i have some other questions about oracle apex too

Answer (score 2):

where the relatonship between tables does not exist - but only if the comparison involves rows in table that are not 'graduated' (I think)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       TABLE1.ID, 
       TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK
FROM TABLE1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.FK_ID_CLASS
   AND TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK <> 'GRADUATED'
WHERE TABLE2.FK_ID_CLASS IS NULL
```

Comment: to define your requirement use sample data, and, expected result. manually prepare an example, this way we avoid confusion of words. it is the very best way to explain what you want

Answer (score 2):

I see some odds with your query:

1. exists part are not related with you main query. I think you need some relation
2. distinct in part not exists are not needed
3. You filter columns with the same conditions as filter main row set

As I understand you want to get all rows from table1 with state 'GRADUATED' int table2 and any row from table1 where rows in table2 are not exists or state not equal 'GRADUATED'

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       t1.ID, 
       t2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK
FROM TABLE1 t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.FK_ID_CLASS
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (
    SELECT NULL /*its not nesessary what you need*/
    FROM TABLE1 sub_t1
    JOIN TABLE2 sub_t2 ON sub_t1.ID = sub_t2.FK_ID_CLASS /* left join replaced to inner */
    WHERE sub_t2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED'
      AND sub_t1.ID = t1.ID /*relation with outer query*/
    )
OR t2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about your question but if you want all the records from table 1 who are not in table 2, you just have to do this :

```
SELECT TABLE1.ID
FROM TABLE1 
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.FK_ID_CLASS
WHERE TABLE2.FK_ID_CLASS IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE1.ID, TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK
  FROM TABLE1
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2
    ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.FK_ID_CLASS
   AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM  TABLE2 t
                    WHERE TABLE1.ID = t.FK_ID_CLASS
                      AND t.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED')
        OR TABLE2.TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED')
```

For the record, conditions on the right table of a `LEFT JOIN` need to be placed inside the `ON()` clause or the join will transfer into an `INNER JOIN` due to `NULL` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have three distinct cases that can be "`OR`ed together" using `UNION`; personally I find keeping all three separated like this makes things much easier to read and understand:

```
--- ID with GRADUATED exists in TABLE2
( SELECT ID, 'GRADUATED' AS TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK
    FROM TABLE1
  INTERSECT 
  SELECT FK_ID_CLASS, 'GRADUATED'
    FROM TABLE2
  WHERE TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED' )

UNION

--- ID without GRADUATED exists in TABLE2
( SELECT ID, 'IN PROGRESS'
    FROM TABLE1
  MINUS
  SELECT FK_ID_CLASS, 'IN PROGRESS'
    FROM TABLE2
   WHERE TRAINING_STATUS_CHECK = 'GRADUATED' )

UNION

--- ID does not exist in TABLE2
( SELECT ID, '{{NONE}}'
    FROM TABLE1
   WHERE ID NOT IN ( SELECT FK_ID_CLASS FROM TABLE2 ) );
```